# changing values in memory is not working pointers

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void reverse(char * str[]) {
    int i;
    int reverse = sizeof(str);

    for(i=0;i<=sizeof(str);i++){
        *str[i]=*str[reverse];
        reverse--;
    }
}

main() {
        char *word;

        printf("Enter a word please=>");
        scanf("%s",word);

        reverse(word);      
        printf("%s",word);
}
```

I am trying to get a string input and pass it to `reverse()` function to reverse the word entered i.e `("abcd" -> "dcba")`, however i am having some difficulty using pointers.

I am not able to change the values held by the `char *word` in the memory.

Comment: Welcome to the fiendishly difficult world of pointers and memory management. It's Really Hard.

Comment: `*str[reverse];` ---> seems you are going out of bounds

Comment: 1) `void reverse(char * str[]) {` str is not a string but an array of pointers (or a pointer to pointer) 2) sizeof does not do what you intend 3) `for(i=0;i<=sizeof(str);i++){` you probably want `<` herte (even though the `sizeof(str)` is clearly wrong

Comment: @pinkpanther i am just swapping place of the first digit with the last digit..its not using the function `reverse()`. maybe you got confused

Comment: @wildplasser the sizeof(str) is working fine at least in my code as it is giving me the correct array size. thanks for the help

Comment: `sizeof(str)` returns the size of a pointer - you want `strlen(str)` instead

Comment: It *could* give you the correct size iff that size happens to be equal to `sizeof (char**)`

Comment: @DeepakTivari what I'm saying is since indices in C are zero based you might have to use reverse-1....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't allocated any storage for `word`.  Change

```
char *word;
scanf("%s",word);
```

to

```
char word[20];
scanf("%19s",word);
```

There are also a number of issues with `reverse`

- Its signature accepts an array of strings rather than a single string (an array of chars).
- You need to use `strlen` to calculate the length of a string.  `sizeof` tells you the size of a `char**` on your platform.
- You reverse the string twice so will currently reverse it then reinstate the original order.
- Your reverse algorithm would include reversing the nul terminator.  This wouldn't normally be considered part of a string and needs to stay at the end of the array to mark the end of the string.

The following (untested) function should be closer to what you want

```
void reverse(char* str) {
    int i;
    int len = strlen(str);
    for (int i=0; i<len/2; i++) {
        char tmp = str[i];
        str[i] = str[len-i-1];
        str[len-i-1] = tmp;
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry but i dont know what length of string the user is going to enter, or should i just put a large number e.g. 100?

Comment: @DeepakTivari: it's very good that you see the problem here. just assuming a maximum input value would make the program vulnerable to buffer overflow shizzle. see http://stackoverflow.com/q/1621394/309483

Comment: @DeepakTivari Yes, you can just choose a suitably large number.  Note that I've also changed the `scanf` call to specify a max size of string to accept to guard against buffer overflow